# VS2012 not detecting external changes

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I got this weird issue, when I make external changes on files (like removing a file or make new ones), Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) doesn't detect the file changes. Right now, I deleted ~15 and copied a lots of new files in windows explorer, but in my solution, it shows the old files and says there is an issue with them.

I turned on "Tools"->"options"->"Environment"->"Documents"->"Detect when file changes outside..." and the one under it. Doesn't help.

(Right now, I am working on an MVC4 project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a somewhat solution:

- Project->Show all files
- Right click on everything you want and select "include in project"

You can do the same, with the files you already deleted, but the VS shows you as an issue. (Exclude from project)