# Visual Studio 2012 detect file changes stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My Visual Studio stopped recognizing external file changes.

I checked the respective options being enabled ('Environment/Documents/Detect when file is changed outside the environment' and 'Environment/Documents/Auto-load changes, if saved).

I restarted Visual Studio as well as my machine.

I tested other software that recognized changes, such as Notepad++, which works just fine.

I tested different Visual Studio projects to check if it has something to do with the project being screwed up somehow - same effect in all projects I tested.

What's going on here?

(There are some SO questions that appear to be related judging by the headline: [*VS2012 not detecting external changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930689/vs2012-not-detecting-external-changes), [*Visual Studio 2012 stopped applying changes to solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610896/visual-studio-2012-stopped-applying-changes-to-solution) and [*Visual Studio 2012 not detecting file change*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726034/visual-studio-2012-not-detecting-file-changes), but all are about different issues.).

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well this morning. Exiting VS and relaunching/opening the project seems to have it working again. Super strange!

Comment: My symptom was differently in that a restart didn't fix it. I just tested it again in response to your comment for the first time since I asked the question - having been using VS2013 since - and somehow now it works again. I guess I'll never find out what that glitch was.